# find and replace regex

Tags: regex, replace, find, digits, kate

I need find and replace the numbers (of footnotes) find "14" and replace with "[14]"
With regular expression, both in kate and sigil, I can **find** the digits: so: find = \d\d

But I cannot find the way to **replace** digits: 
not works: replace = [\d\d]

Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Try `find = (\d\d)` and try `replace = [\1]`

Comment: It works. Thank you